# How to change the UILabel content by tapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I add a tap gesture on my label but I couldn't retrieve the tapped label in the selector function. I mean, for example, my function is like this:

```
-(void)changeLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{}
```

If this gesture is added on a imageview, I can get the imageview by using sender.view.
But since it's a uilabel I don't know to get it and then change text content.

Hope my question is clear...

Comment: Huh? Isn't an `UILabel` a view too?

Comment: using `UIButtonView` would be great since buttons are made for tap and any such events while `UILabelView` is to just show a text i.e to notify user.

Answer (score 2):

Set the interaction to enabled, then add it as you normally would.

My example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainLabel.text = @"This is my label";
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecongizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeText)];
    self.mainLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.mainLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecongizer];
}

-(void)changeText
{
    NSArray *randomNames = @[@"Jim", @"Bob", @"John", @"Peter"];
    self.mainLabel.text = [randomNames objectAtIndex:arc4random() % 4];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your UILabel's `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES. I believe this property is defaulted to NO on new instances of UILabel.

```
self.yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear button to on top of your `UILabel` with an identical frame

Then create an `IBAction` for the button touch, and handle changing the labels text in there.

Comment: This would be a bit of a hack. There are systems in place to do this correctly, using the way the system is intended to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a UIButton above the label that has the same frame as the label and very low opacity, and have the button perform the action.

Comment: This would be a bit of a hack. There are systems in place to do this correctly, using the way the system is intended to work.